# Jquery: Clear Specific form field on checkbox click

Tags: jquery, onclick, field

I am trying to clear only specific ID input field on my checkbox click. I am switching two fieldset on checkbox click and I want to clear specific ID fields from click on checkbox from all fieldset.

I got this script but its clearing everything from my form and that's what not I am looking but only specific ID fields.

```
function clear_form_elements(ele) {

    $(ele).find(':input').each(function() {
        switch(this.type) {
            case 'text':
            case 'textarea':
                $(this).val('');
                break;              
                this.checked = false;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: If you know the ID (or can abstract the ID from some property on the checkbox) why not use $('#myField').val(''); instead of a loop?  And if you want to keep this approach, use $('input[type=text], textarea',elem) to limit your search just to inputs and textareas

Comment: Nick's method is the way to go, there are selectors you can use even for dynamic ID and will only write one line of code to handle multiple fields

Comment: Nick can you please give me an example. unable to understand how to write what you said. As I am new to jquery and php even. In fact I have tried one thing and it works for me but want to know your method too. and if will small and easy than would like to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your form structure looks like, but if you want to clear text, textarea, checkbox, or select values by id you could use

```
$(ele).find('#id').val('');
```

Assuming:

```
1. the variable 'ele' represents the form jquery object. 
2. '#id' is the id of the field you want to remove the value for, and
3. that your javascript may be included on other pages that use the same '#id'
```

if '#id' is unique throughout your site, or your javascript is page-specific, Nick's method will work fine.

```
$('#id').val('');
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't works full but I have tried and modified a bit and it works fine. `$(ele).find('#id').val('');` in your code it wasn't considering any input field so I wrote '$(ele).find('.clearform :input').each(function()` and it works for me. However my form structure is is little different. where clearform is a div group of few input elements, So may be that also could be the reason

In fact I am also looking for Nick reply if as he said code can be small I would like to see that too.

but I am looking for Nick's reply regarding what he said.